# Can a dead SSD appear in the bios list of drives?

Tags: boot, ssd, bios

My parent's work laptop started showing an issue with its boot drive (its only drive). I thought the drive could be dead so I got into the bios and checked the list of detected devices and the SSD was listed on it. I didn't want to change any boot options because it's a corporate-owned device, so it's the company's IT dept responsibility, but it made me curious about the topic.

I googled it but nothing came up, so here I am.

Answer (score 1):

A drive (SSD or Hard drive) may be electronically working but the media not readable. That is what you have. It is not uncommon that BIOS can see the drive but the data is inaccessible.